# Need to insert a tab in between every instance of a lowercase letter immediately followed by an uppercase letter

Tags: regex, textpad

I am using TextPad 6 find and replace feature using regular expressions.

In the document I need to insert a tab in between every instance where a lowercase letter is followed by an uppercase letter that has no space between them.

But I cannot find the right regex combination to make this simple task work.

Example:

I want to find:

```
fooBar
```

replace with

```
foo [tab] Bar
```

This will result being a delimited file.

I have used

```
FIND:[a-z][A-Z] 
REPLACE: &\t 
RESULT: fooB    ar
```

OR

```
FIND:[a-z][A-Z] 
REPLACE:\t&
RESULT: fo  oBar
```

OR

```
FIND:[a-z][A-Z] 
REPLACE:&\t&
RESULT: fo  oBar
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps use parentheses? I don't use textpad so I don't know how it's regex works but parentheses help in notepad++,  which is what u use.

Comment: If TextPad allows look-arounds, try: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` and replace with `\t`.

Comment: TextPad does not recognize (?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]) I tried it with posix enabled and not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups:

```
FIND:([a-z])([A-Z])
REPLACE:\1\t\2
```

Comment: This find replace with posix enabled returns Find fooBar and replaces with f oo Ba r

Comment: @user2683415 the solution raina77ow gave works, but you just need to check the Match Case checkbox in the Replace dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Like raina77ow said you need to capture the regex matched groups. This can be done by adding parenthesis.

I think this should do it.

```
Find:([a-z]+)([A-Za-z]+)
Replace: \1\t\2
```

Comment: This Find:([a-z]+)([A-Za-z]+)
Replace: \1\t\2